# Print XPS document without open the dialog box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, xps

How to print a XPS document,which is in my application start up path without opening the `OpenFileDialog`?

Comment: Is that working fine with `OpenFileDialogue`?

Comment: What do you mean? Printing to a xps file or printing xps file to printer? What's the role of `OpenFileDialog`?

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei Printing a XPS file to Printer

Comment: @SruthiSuresh: still few questions remains - What's the role of `OpenFileDialog`? and is that working fine with OpenFileDialogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [PrintQueue.AddJob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552914(v=vs.110).aspx). That particular method can be used to print an xps document without any additional UI interactions.